# Parse file in Xtext MWE2 workflow

Tags: xtext

I would like to parse a file within an MWE2 workflow, e.g. by giving the `org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils.Reader` component a file written in my DSL rather than the XMI representation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively have a look at org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.UriBasedReader

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/831365/

```
Workflow {  
    component = org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.Reader {
        register = org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslStandaloneSetup {}
        path = "modeldir"
        loadResource = {
            slot = "models"
        }
    }
}
```

Adjusted to the answer of Christian when using a single file it can be written

```
Workflow {  
    component = org.eclipse.xtext.mwe.UriBasedReader {
        register = org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDslStandaloneSetup {}
        uri = "model.file"
        loadResource = {
            slot = "model"
        }
    }
}
```